# Accessing list or raw data for blocked numbers?

Tags: contacts, backup, phone-app

I'm using some vendor' stock ROM but I as far as I understand it still uses *Blocked Numbers Storage* - `com.android.providers.blockednumber`, however I cant seems to find a way to export or back it up.

Is it possible with Tasker?
Is it possible with root? Any API that can get me access to it, if I have root and will set my test palceholder app as a default dialer? I'm willing to use some Xamarin template to make it work.

Comment: Blocked numbers are accessible through contacts APIs. Stock Contacts app can show blocked numbers, as well as add and remove them. Or with root access: `sqlite3 /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.blockednumber/databases/blockednumbers.db 'select * from blocked'`

Comment: Huh, interesting, it is empty.

Comment: Unless you're really sure that it's using the public shared provider "Blocked Numbers Storage", there's another possibility that the Dialer app is using a its app's storage/DB for blocked numbers.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible that MIUI is a special snowflake that does that it wants.