# Where is the phone blacklist stored?

Tags: call-screening, spam

I have a problem with spam calls, they call me many times a day. To solve this problem, I've tried many call blockers apps (NoPhoneSpam, Calls Blacklist, CallBlocker, etc...) and none of them work. Some of them worked for a while, but then stopped to work.

The spammers use a prefix and change the last 3 or 4 numbers of the phone, and I want to block them all. The android native phone app allows me to block numbers, and it works, but without wildcards, so I can't block all numbers with a given prefix without entering them one by one (not an option).

I want to know if the Phone app blacklist is stored anywhere that I can edit it with a text editor, or if there is a way to add phones to it using terminal, so I can write a script to add all phones I want to block.

Comment: The phone app data is likely inside [app-specific storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) which is inaccessible without root access. On the other hand, related/possible dupe: [Can I block calls based on a specific number prefix or pattern?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110470/44325)

Comment: While the phone apps are free to maintain their own list of blocked numbers, Android also has a Content Provider (with the app name: Blocked Numbers Storage) which the apps can use to share a common blocked number repository very much like Contacts and Messages. The stock phone app in AOSP uses the same blocked number provider which saves its database in `/data/user_de/<USER_ID>/com.android.providers.blockednumber/databases/blockednumbers.db`.

Comment: Related: [Accessing list or raw data for blocked numbers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/227207/218526)